# mod_security on an OWA front end

Tags: reverse-proxy, outlook-web-app, mod-security

When using mod_security (installed from EPEL) with apache 2 on a centos box, sometimes users are unable to send messages - im having trouble tracing the rule back, the only place i get to is 'inbound anomaly score too high'

anyone know what i should be looking for, how to trace mod_security stuff, or better yet specifically what OWA in 2003 is doing that it doesnt like?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at Apache error log? If you did, you will see the rule which spawned that message, something like this:

> [Mon Dec 13 10:44:16 2010] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] ModSecurity:
>   Warning. Operator GE matched 20 at
>   TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file
>   "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"]
>   [line "35"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly
>   Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score:
>   20, SQLi=, XSS=): Request Missing an
>   Accept Header"] [hostname
>   "xx"] [uri
>   "/index.html"] [unique_id
>   "hKt1A38AAAEAADzVdd4AAAAH"]

Answer (score 1):

I've heard from a working colleague that it's pretty hard to secure OWA with mod_security.

But you could enable the debug logging of mod_security:

```
SecDebugLog /usr/local/apache/logs/modsec-debug.log
SecDebugLogLevel 4
```